# Custom matchmaking using Google play game services

Tags: google-play-services, multiplayer, google-play-games

I use GPGS for realtime multiplayer in a game I am developing. I can connect to other users just fine, but I was wondering: is there was a way to set a criteria for who you get auto matched with? For example , could I match players based on their levels or some other criteria like win/loss ratio? As of right now it is completely random and I don't think it offers a very good user experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is. When you create your RoomConfig for match making you can provide AutoMatchCriteria. The API just uses a bitmask, so it is up to you what data you put in that bit mask:

[createAutoMatchCriteria](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/realtime/RoomConfig.html#createAutoMatchCriteria(int,%20int,%20long))

> **exclusiveBitMask**: Exclusive bitmasks for the automatching request. The
>   logical AND of each pairing of automatching requests must equal zero
>   for auto-match. If there are no exclusivity requirements for the game,
>   this value should just be set to 0.

You can see it being used in the sample code here: [Developing Real-Time Multiplayer Games](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/realtimeMultiplayer#invite_players_option).